# How to reference TailwindCSS color in CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, themes

Can we reference the TailwindCSS color code in CSS?

I have a CSS file like this:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 220 14% 96%;
  }
}
```

The background variable is equivalent to TailwindCSS `bg-gray-100`. How can I define the variable to something like this:

```css
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: bg-gray-100;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `bg` prefix is the final CSS rule for this specific style. The actual path is `colors.gray.100` as Noah demonstrated below. Here is the [source code (v3.3.3)](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/v3.3.3/src/public/colors.js#L31) of the `colors.js` file that Tailwind uses. You can find all of the colors defined here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `theme()` function provided by tailwind.

```css
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: theme(colors.gray.100);
  }
}
```

More information about the theme funtion [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme)

Comment: Thank you, @noah1400.

The configuration in `tailwind.config.js` is referencing the value in a hsl function: `hsl(var(--background))`. Do you know if TailwindCSS has a variable for hsl value for it?

Comment: No Tailwind does not store colors as hsl values